# vscode cannot find python libraries which spyder can (both launched from anaconda)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to migrate from spyder to vscode, but vscode is having trouble finding my libraries I have pulled from github. It will import numpy, and other things I installed via pip in the spyder consol a long time ago, but not the libraries in the GitHub folder - except the one where the current file is located! I have no importing problems in Spyder, and both spyder and vscode are launched through anaconda. I have checked with os.path.dirname(sys.executable) that both of them are using the same python interpreter, so I don't know what else I can do! Any tips?

Comment: That is the correct behavior for Python.  It looks like you added the GitHub package paths to Spyder somehow?

Comment: @James yes this is true. I have two libraries out of four in the Spyder pythonpathmanager tool. But I can still import the other two from Spyder and none from VSCode. I have been trying to put these libraries in vscode path but can't find a way. I put these libraries in the windows path now and it still can't find them.

Answer (score 0):

You encounter environment problems when using python in vscode, selecting the correct interpreter for the current workspace by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter` will generally solve most of the problems.

[image]

In addition, you need to use the **Python** extension to execute the code. If you have *Code Runner* installed, don't use it.

[image]